# is there a pipe map in bash?

Tags: bash

```
cmd1 | cmd2
```

will call cmd2 only once with cmd1 output as argument. What i want is call cmd2 one by one with each line of cmd1 output as argument. Maybe something looks like:

```
cmd1 | map cmd2
```

I know I can write one by myself, just want to know is there a built-in support already?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cmd1 | xargs -l cmd2
```

This is my favorite way. Thank you Paulo Ebermann!

Comment: I(maybe all Mac users) prefer `cmd1 | xargs -L1 cmd2` which is more universal, for `-l` option is supported in GNU(synonym for -L[max-lines]) but not in BSD.

Comment: @HuiZheng Nice to see you here again!

Comment: It would be nice to have a deeper explanation to be honest

Answer (score 4):

```
for i in `cmd1`; do cmd2 $i; done
```

should do it.

Comment: what i really want is something for pipe processing, so this is not the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
cmd1 | while read x
do
  cmd2 $x
done
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem, but i'd like to have it to be a simple and general map function.

Answer (score 1):

use xargs

```
cmd1|xargs cmd2
```

eg:

```
ls xyz*|xargs grep "abc"
```

abc will be searched in all the files whose name starts with  xyz

Comment: Note that `xargs` doesn't help when you want to call `cmd2` exactly **once** for each line of `cmd1`. It will call `cmd2` as few times as possible!

Comment: @Joachim Sauer, you are right :)

Comment: @Joachim: There is the `-l` switch to `xargs`, which does this, though.

Comment: xargs -l is what i want, good!